# 400 Error In HTTP Post Request

Tags: angularjs, http, ionic-framework

```
 $scope.isValid = {
    "AppURL" : 'http://10.154.2.38/admin',
      "Pwd":   str.toString(),
      "RandomSalt" : random_encrypt.toString(),
      "UserName" : $scope.loginData.username.toString()       
}


$http({
        method : 'post',
        data: $scope.isValid,
        headers: {
        'Content-Type': undefined,
        'origin' : '*'
        },
        url : $scope.rooturl+"/isValidUser"
}).success(function(response) {
      console.log("Success");
})
```

This is my Http Request but it gives 400 Bad Request and give it 200 Ok in Get Request!

The following is an example request JSON body:

```
{
    "AppURL":"String content",
    "Pwd":"String content",
    "RandomSalt":"String content",
    "UserName":"String content"
}
```

Comment: thats perfectly acceptable. service endpoints accepts one of the HttpVerbs like GET, POST, PUT, DELETE, PATCH.... In your case, the service accepts a GET and not a POST

Comment: @naveen right. However, I'd prefer returning `405 - Method not allowed`

Comment: that's the problem it returnig 400 Bad Request Error!! I don't know why all is this happened?